# Laravel 9 not loading Vite & Tailwind Assets on Production

Tags: laravel, https, vite

I am using Laravel 9 with tailwindcss and Vite on my development server to develop my project. On development server everything is working fine but when I uploaded my laravel project to production server running cpanel, none of my assets are loading properly. the error I'm getting :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://0.0.0.0:5173/@vite/client'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://0.0.0.0:5173/resources/css/app.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I've tried to use        URL::forceScheme('https');
in AppServiceProvider but to no avail.

Changed this line:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

in my guest.blade.php and app.blade.php file to this line:

```
<link href="{{ secure_asset('/resources/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ secure_asset('/resources/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
    GET https://sarkercompanies.com/resources/resources/js/app.js 404 (Not Found) 12:28:20.818 
    GET https://sarkercompanies.com/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help as none of the solutions are working for me on production.

Answer (score 0):

Since I host my Laravel app on AWS with an Elastic Load Balancer configuring a trusted proxy fixed this problem for me:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Consider trusting all proxies:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#trusting-all-proxies

I also forced Laravel to use the https-Scheme for URLs in the AppServiceProvider boot-method:

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```